# If I sign up for the 3 free months of Apple Music, do I keep Match-ed songs when the trial ends?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, apple-music

If I sign up for the Apple Music free trial (which [now includes audio fingerprinting iTunes Match](http://www.loopinsight.com/2016/07/18/apple-begins-rolling-out-itunes-match-with-audio-fingerprint-to-apple-music-subscribers/)), will I keep my (DRM-free but watermarked) Matched music when the trial ends?

Comment: No, it's not. That post doesn't take into account the new Apple Music/audio-fingerprinting iTunes Match integration.

Comment: I'm not sure what the audio-fingerprinting has to do with your question, based on the link you provided.  That's just a way to make sure iTunes Match has the correct version of your song matched (instead of using a live version for a studio track, for example).  If you owned the song prior to having Apple Music you'll still own the song after the trial expires.  Can you explain how the audio-fingerprint factors in to your question?  I'm not understanding it completely.

Comment: It's new, and at one point tracks matched with Apple Music *would not* stay as part of your library after your trial expired, I was under the impression. Have you got a link to an Apple resource that verifies "if you owned the song prior to having Apple Music you'll still own the song after the trial expires"? I can't find one dated post the change.

Comment: I would have to look for that reference.  I'm going by memory that Match worked by adding songs you already owned to the cloud allowing you to access them anywhere.  I could be wrong since they made changes recently but you'd still own the songs you bought, they just wouldn't be available in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be sure you have downloaded a copy of all music before the period ends. You don't lose anything stored locally unless you delete the local files, and even if you delete the local files - as long as you re-download them before the end - you will have playable music locally.

This is covered in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204962

Comment: This reference refers to the previous configuration of Apple Music and Match, and I do not have confidence it is still accurate.

Comment: I haven't tested an expire since the change, but I'm not seeing any difference on my library files since the change. Are you thinking there's a bug in the implementation?